# Enlighten me about JQuery Each and Undefined

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I am almost done writing my widget - my first real venture into JQuery, and I cannot figure out my last problem...  I have added my JSON Array to the bottom of this post...  I am trying to figure out why my last two script lines in my JQuery.each are listing, but not giving fields, instead, giving Undefined.

```
<script>
    var jsonURL = "//myurl.com/api.php/content_data?filter[]=date_activation,lte,9/16/2017&filter [] = date_expiration, is, & filter[] = publish, eq, public & columns = id_cr, title, teaser & order = title & page = 1 ";
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: jsonURL,
        success: searchCallback
      });
    });

    function searchCallback(data) {
      jQuery(".here").append(data.content_data.results);
        var content_data = data.content_data;
      jQuery.each(content_data, function(index, content_dat) {
        console.log(index, content_dat); 

          jQuery(".here").append('<h1>' + content_dat.title + '</h1>');
        jQuery(".here").append('<p>' + content_dat.id_cr + '</p>');

      });
    };
</script>

JSON Array:
content_data    
 columns    
  0 "id_cr"
  1 "teaser"
  2 "title"
 records    
  0 
   0    69425
   1    "<p>Hurricane Harvey has been one of the strongest weather storms to hit the U.S. this year and has caused severe flooding in Texas and parts of Louisiana.</p>"
   2    "Hurricane Harvey Aftermath"
 results    1
```

Comment: Are you saying that `content_dat.title` is undefined?

Comment: Sample of the response (content_dat) would be helpful to see what you're accessing.

Comment: Instead of "// This works!", could you inform what the exact object value is of what you log?

Comment: @user1255154 Just having a look again at your code, should you not pass 'data.content_data.results' to JQuery.each?

Comment: The result of my array is: columns Array [ "id_cr", "teaser", "title" ]  records Array [ Array[3] ] 
The last two lines of my code give Undefined for both title and id_cr

     <h1>Undefined</h1>
     <p>Undefined</p>

Comment: @user1255154 What is the exact value of `content_data`? And please format it in the question so it's readable.

Comment: JSON array added to the original question - cleaned up question as well...

Comment: Yes, it lists the titles of the field, the field data is under records.

Comment: @user1255154 The "records" part of your response just contains a nested array?

Comment: @user1255154 My last question was an accident. See my new question.

Comment: Yes, just a nested array of all of the records.  I am sure that I am just not writing something correctly in my Jquery script, but I don't have enough experience to know what I am missing.  I have done a lot of reading today, but this piece I have not figured out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content_dat` is an array, not an object with named fields; it doesn't have `title` and `id_cr` fields. Just access each element of the array via subscripting (`[]`) like you would any other array:

```
jQuery(".here").append('<h1>' + content_dat[2] + '</h1>');

jQuery(".here").append('<p>' + content_dat[0] + '</p>');
```

Comment: Getting closer! I get the title and the teaser to show up now, but I still have undefined on the page, too - I am not sure why...  You can see it here ::disabled link::  I only want the title and teaser of the article to show, not the header or the undefined...

Comment: @user1255154 It's probably the same problem. And your question doesn't show anything about the body of the page.

Comment: @user1255154 What is undefined? Your original question only has those 2 lines that I corrected in my answer.

Comment: This is a widget, so there is nothing else to the page except for a div to hold the results.  The script above makes up all the code on the page.

Comment: Again, what is undefined? You said "but I still have undefined on the page", but your original code only shows using the title and id_cr from the response JSON, and you said that those are fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much, you got me to look at this in the right way, so I am accepting your answer.  I also needed to update this line: var content_data = data.content_data.records; to include records... that was it, thank you!

Comment: @user1255154 No problem. In the future though, please make sure you're including all the relevant information from the start. If your question is about using JSON data, the JSON you're trying to use (or at least its structure) should be included in the question.